# Cannot get simple while loop working in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, infinite

```
LETTERS = "abc"
correct = "cab "
guess = ""

while guess != correct:
    for i in LETTERS:
        position = random.randrange(len(LETTERS))
        guess += LETTERS[position]
        LETTERS = LETTERS[:position] + LETTERS[(position + 1):]
    print(guess)
```

I'm new in Python and I want to make this simple program:

- With the letters "abc", jumble them and create a new three-lettter word randomly.
- Print that jumble
- Continue doing this loop until the computer jumbles "cab".
- Then stop.

I came up with this code, and it gives me an infinite loop. I can't figure out why is doing it. I'm sure it's something easy but I can't see it. Need some help! Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to end your `correct` value with a space?

Comment: And did you mean to reset your guesses after they fail?

Comment: OP is also altering `LETTERS` on every iteration of the for-loop. Needs to alter a copy of LETTERS instead with a `myLetters = LETTERS[:]` immediately inside the while-loop (and reset `guess` too)

Answer (score 3):

You have three problems that I can see:

1. `"cab "` has a space in it, and `LETTERS` does not have a space. So you'll never be able to guess a space
2. You don't reset `guess`. You simply keep adding to it
3. You change `LETTERS` in your for-loop, so in the second iteration of your while-loop, it will be completely empty.

This is how I would go about doing what you're trying to do (with minimal modification):

```
_LETTERS = "abc"
correct = "cab"
guess = ""

while guess != correct:
    LETTERS = _LETTERS[:]
    guess = ""
    for i in LETTERS:
        position = random.randrange(len(LETTERS))
        guess += LETTERS[position]
        LETTERS = LETTERS[:position] + LETTERS[(position + 1):]
    print(guess)
```

Here's how I would do a random search (which is what you're trying to do):

```
guess = "abc"
correct = "cab"

while guess != correct:
    guess = list(guess)
    random.shuffle(guess)
    guess = ''.join(guess)
    print(guess)
print(guess)
```

Of course, there are better techniques to correctly guess `"cab"`. If you really want to try an exhaustive search, then you could use a backtracking DFS:

```
def DFS(letters, correct, sofar=None)
    if sofar is None:
        sofar = ''
    if not letters:
        if sofar == correct:
            print("Yay! I found it")
        else:
            print("Oops! I found %s instead" %sofar)
    else:
        for i,char in enumerate(letters):
            DFS(letters[:i]+letters[i+1:], correct, sofar+char)
```

Comment: Your second code snippet doesn't work. You're throwing away the shuffled list.

Comment: @user2357112: False. `random.shuffle` is IN-PLACE. It returns `None`

Comment: In-place on a list you immediately throw away.

Comment: @user2357112: good catch. I totally missed that. It's fixed now. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for all your answers!

That space at "cab" was a typo. It wasn't meant to be there!
I see now what was the problem haha, what a silly thing. Now it works fine.

Also thank you for the random.shuffle thing. I didn't know that one!

Answer (score 2):

Your `correct` value contains a space, but your loop never generates spaces:

```
correct = "cab "
```

Remove that space:

```
correct = "cab"
```

Next, your loop reduces `LETTERS` to an empty string, so only *once* does your loop produce a random `guess`, but afterwards, you forever are stuck with `LETTERS = ''`, so no `for` loop is run.

You'd be better off using `random.shuffle` to produce guesses:

```
LETTERS = list("abc")
correct = "cab"

while True:
    random.shuffle(LETTERS)
    guess = ''.join(LETTERS)
    if guess == correct:
        print(guess)
        break
```